# Replace the particular part of string?

Tags: c#

I want to replace particular string  in another string if it contain that word . example 
 give string is "asp,mvc,c#,wpf" and another string is "<b>asp</b>,<b>wpf</b>" and my final result should be "<b>asp</b>,mvc,c#,<b>wpf</b>" , i have no idea about how to do it in c# code .please help me.

Comment: are the bold tags required?  do you always want any bold tag to end up in the result?

Comment: do the values in the second string always appear in the first string?

Comment: @matt actually i am using elastic search , in which i getting two kind of result first one is getting all fields and other one is highlighted terms , now i need to replace my highlighted terms within all fields so that my result will have the  all fields with highlighted terms if it contain keyword

Comment: @kmacdonald yes second string always appears in first without bold tags , i need to add bold tags to that particular word , cannot go for `foreach` my record will have 1000 results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var str = "asp,mvc,c#,wpf";
var anotherStr = "<b>asp</b>,<b>wpf</b>";
var myArr = anotherStr.Replace("<b>", "").Replace("</b>", "").Split(',');
foreach (string value in myArr)
{
    str = str.Replace(value, "<b>" + value + "</b>");
}
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: i will have more than 1000 record like this , so it will take longer time

Comment: so? You have to use regex, which will be even more slower. My suggestion is to go with my answer